# How to fade alpha on GameObject using Standard Shader?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, leantween

How to simply fade a game object that has a Standard shader applied?

This is my code. If I switch the shader to Sprites.default it works.

```
public void foo(float val)
{
     _isFade=true;
     float time=2.0f;
     float alphaVal=0.0f;
     LeanTween.alpha(gameObject, alphaVal, time);

     Debug.Log("YES calling fade in foo !!!! and gameObject = "+gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Many shaders don't support transparency, so you'll need to make sure that you're using one that does.

Comment: @EvilTak post it as the answer

Comment: @EmilioMartinez there we go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the type of the Standard shader set as "Fade" or "Transparent" on your material.

Comment: works using Fade but now my objects seem transparent and they should be opaque. Z buffer issue?

Comment: If you want to "fade" the object, that means transparency isn't it? If you want the object to have like a Glass like look then use Transparent. If you slowly want to make the object dissapear or something like that use Fade. Refer to [this link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameters.html) and go under the Rendering Modes section for more info.

Comment: not sure you read my comment. I have a common problem with Fade causing Z buffer issues, ie objects aren't layered properly and appear transparent. Will post my solution tomorrow